# DRF: Using 'SlugRelatedField' on the 'ImageField'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The django models are:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class PostImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post,
        related_name=images,
    )
```

The serializer is:

```
class PostSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    images = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='image',
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
    )

class Meta:
    model = PostModel
    fields = ('name' 'images',)
```

The serializer data output is:

```
[
    {
        "name": 'Name 1', 
        "images": [
            <ImageFieldFile: 1.jpg>,
            <ImageFieldFile: 2.jpg>,
        ],
    },
    {
        "name": 'Name 2', 
        "images": [
            <ImageFieldFile: 5.jpg>,
        ],
    }
]
```

But when tried to get the ***paginated response*** of the same data, it crashes with error `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)"`

Its because of the presence `ImageFieldFile` instead of the URL.

How to get the ***absolute url*** (MEDIA_URL+image-relative-url) of the images instead of the `ImageFieldFile` ?

Answer (score 5):

Was able to figure out looking into `to_representation` implementation of `FileField`.

```py
class ImageUrlField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        url = instance.image.url
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        if request is not None:
            return request.build_absolute_uri(url)
        return url

class PostSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    images = serializers.ImageUrlField(many=True, read_only=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with ImageFields, so there may be another solution, but for sure this will work:

```
class ImageUrlField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        # Build absolute URL (next line is just sample code)
        str = settings.MEDIA_URL + str(value.image) 
        return str

class PostSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    images = serializers.ImageUrlField(many=True, read_only=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I've added the solution that I'm using. The implementations of `to_representation` is in sync with the DRF.